# How to display category description only on the first page in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to display category description only on the first page. The following code is not working - any idea how to fix it?

```
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php 
    if (strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) = 0 || $_GET['p'] = '1') 
        {

        echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description'); 

        }

    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one :

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
<?php $currentPage = (int) Mage::App()->getRequest()->getParam('p'); 
if($currentPage <= 1):
?>
<div class="category-description std">
    <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the products list toolbar to know if you're on the first page :

```
if ($this->isContentMode()
    || $this->getChild('product_list')->getToolbarBlock()->isFirstPage()) {
    // Display description (assuming that content mode is always first page)
}
```